# How do take an user's input to make a two-dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to make a two-dimensional array using the inputs from the user. However, the variables in my code are fixed. Thus, when a user inputs an integer x, the two-dimensional array does not have x rows and columns. How can I fix my code?

This is what I have so far:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner (); 
int size = s.nextInt();
    int a1 = new int [size]; 
    int a2 = new int [size];
    int a3 = new int [size];
for (int i = 0; i<= size; i++) {
    int value = (int)(Math.random()*1); 
    a1[i] = value; 
    int value = (int)(Math.random()*1); 
    a2[i] = value; 
    int value = (int)(Math.random()*1); 
    a3[i] = value; 
System.out.print(a1[i] + " " + a2[i] + " " + a3[i]);
```

The output should instead look like the following:

```
Enter the size of the array: 3

0 1 0

1 0 1

0 1 1
```

I appreciate any help or suggestions!

Comment: This `int value = (int)(Math.random()*1);` will return same as `int value = (int) Math.random();`, just `0`. You need to multiply by `* 2`

Comment: Also in the future you will want to improve your question by stating what is wrong with your code attempt. Please check out the [ask].

Comment: Your current code assumes that the user will always enter a size of 3, since you have hard-coded variables `a1`, `a2`, and `a3`.  You need to find a way to have the number of arrays be variable.  Hint: more loops.  Oh, and here's hint #2: You can create a two-dimensional array like so: `int[][] a = new int[numRows][numCols]`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I will keep that in mind the next time I post a question. Thanks!

Comment: Fix your question *now* please

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I just did. Let me know if it needs further edits. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you want to do this:

```
System.out.println("Please enter two-dimentional array size:");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = sc.nextInt();
Random rand = new Random();;
int[][] array = new int[n][n];
for (int[] i : array) {
    for (int j : i) {
        j = rand.nextInt(2);
        System.out.print(j + " ");
    }
System.out.println("\n");
```

Comment: There's no need to instantiate a new `Random` object for every element in the array.

Answer (score -1):

Here:

```
System.out.print("Enter the size of the array: ");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = sc.nextInt();
int twoD[][] = new int[n][n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    twoD[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
  }
}
for (int[] x : twoD) {
  for (int y : x) {
    System.out.print(y + "  ");
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

Output:

```
Enter the size of the array: 4
1  0  0  0  
1  0  0  1  
0  1  0  0 
1  0  1  1
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. The code works, so I'm not sure why it's downvoted.

Comment: @JSW Thanks. I wanted to keep it simple, there are million easy/complex ways to do it but we are driven to encourage people to understand easily.